# How to get results from MySql DB using and send them back to API.ai

Tags: javascript, mysql, dialogflow-es

I need some assistance in figuring out the syntax for SQL queries while using them through an api.ai webhook & connecting to a Google cloud Mysql database.
Although the query is working, the 'request gets timed out'

```
 'use strict';
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.name = (req, res) => { 

    let action = req.body.result['action'];

if (action === 'apple') {


    callDB().then((output) => {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(output));
    }).catch((error) => {

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.send(JSON.stringify(error));
    });

}
};

function callDB() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    try {

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "<host>",
            user: "<user>",
            password: "<pass>",
            database: "<DB>"
        });

        connection.query("SELECT description AS solution FROM mtable WHERE title LIKE '%Breakfast%'", function (error, results, fields) {
            if (!error) {

                let response = "The result is: " + results[0].solution;
                response = response.toString();
                let output = {'speech': response, 'displayText': response};
                console.log(output);
                resolve(output);

            } else {

                let output = {'speech': 'Error. Query Failed.', 'displayText': 'Error. Query Failed4.'};
                console.log(output);
                reject(output);

            }
        });
        connection.end();

    } catch (err) {
        let output = {'speech': 'try-catch block error', 'displayText': 'try-catch block error3'};
        console.log(output);
        reject(output);

    }

}
);
}
```

If i substitute the query with this, it works :

'SELECT description AS solution FROM mtable WHERE id LIKE 1001'

id is a column name with only id`s

title is a column name with titles such as Breakfast wrap, etc.

this is part of the error shown on webhook json:

```
"metadata": {
  "intentId": "<id>",
  "webhookUsed": "true",
  "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
  "webhookResponseTime": 5000,

 "status": {
 "code": 206,
 "errorType": "partial_content",
 "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.",
 "webhookTimedOut": true
  },
```

I referenced the following thread for the code,
[How to get results from MySql DB using node.js MySQL and send them back to API.ai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45933303/how-to-get-results-from-mysql-db-using-node-js-mysql-and-send-them-back-to-api-a)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo in your query string declaration (near '%Breakfast%'') :

```
connection.query('SELECT description AS solution FROM mtable WHERE title LIKE '%Breakfast%'', function (error, results, fields) {
```

When assigning your query string to a variable, 'SELECT description AS solution FROM mtable WHERE title LIKE '%Breakfast%'' is interpreted as a number (because of the % operator).

Does fixing your single quotes help in any way?

```
connection.query("SELECT description AS solution FROM mtable WHERE title LIKE '%Breakfast%'", function (error, results, fields) {
```

Comment: Greetings, That did indeed resolve the error, however I am still not getting any data from the DB. The json simply says timed out. (API.ai only waits for 5 secs before timing out. What could be the solution?  "status": {
    "code": 206,
    "errorType": "partial_content",
    "errorDetails": "Webhook call failed. Error: Request timeout.",
    "webhookTimedOut": true

Comment: I am not familiar with API.ai. I only spotted something weird regarding your JavaScript code. 
If it solved the first issue you mentionned in your question, I suggest you update your question with information regarding your current issue (with the error message) and most important, add a tag for each technology involved (api.ai, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Problem has to be on your server side with mysql.  I do this daily and it works just fine with mysql in under 5 seconds for queries.

Could be your where clause is creating full table scans, thus timing out back to Diagflow (>5 seconds) or the db connection is falling out.

You need to set timers in front of the routine and the end cycle, look at your durations.  Run your query from a bash script alone and see how long it takes.  You'll find where the timeout is happening.  Having search parms (%) on both sides of the criteria will definitely take longer than a search string start only (meaning search starting with) vs. %search% (find any substring that contains).

Good luck.